# S3 Bucket not created when I run the code in browser?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browserify

When i run the below code in console like myFunc.myfunc("SomeText"), it creates the bucket but when I use the same function on button, it doesn't create anything. Sometimes it does create but you have to wait around 20-30 minutes before you get it right next time.

I am using node.js at the client side, browserify to make the require() work on client side and cors-anywhere  for CORS policy.

JS File-

// Load the SDK and UUID

```
function uploadToS3(dataForBody) {

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');   //Browserify will be used and bundled in uploadDocsBundle
    var uuid = require('uuid');



    AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'my access key id';
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'my secret access id';
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';


    // Create an S3 client
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    // Create a bucket and upload something into it
    var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
    var keyName = 'hello_world.txt';
    s3.createBucket({ Bucket: bucketName }, function () {

        var params = {
            Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: dataForBody
        };
        s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) 
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
        });
    });

}

(function () {
    var cors_api_host = 'cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com';
    var cors_api_url = 'https://' + cors_api_host + '/';
    var slice = [].slice;
    var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        var args = slice.call(arguments);
        var targetOrigin = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/i.exec(args[1]);
        if (targetOrigin && targetOrigin[0].toLowerCase() !== origin &&
            targetOrigin[1] !== cors_api_host) {
            args[1] = cors_api_url + args[1];
        }
        return open.apply(this, args);
    };
})();



======================================================

HTML File
 <button type="submit" onClick="myFunc.myfunc('hello')" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

Edit2:-
=======

// Load the SDK and UUID
module.exports = { myfunc: uploadToS3 };
function uploadToS3(dataForBody) {

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');   //Browserify will be used and bundled in uploadDocsBundle
    var uuid = require('uuid');





    AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'AccessKey';
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'SecretAccessID';
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';




    // Create a bucket and upload something into it
    var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
    var keyName = 'hello_world2.txt';
    var bucketPromise = new AWS.S3().createBucket({ Bucket: bucketName }).promise();
 //Handle promise fulfilled/rejected states
   bucketPromise.then(
     function (data) {
            // Create params for putObject call
          var objectParams = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Hello World!' };

         // Create object upload promise

      var uploadPromise = new AWS.S3().putObject(objectParams).promise();
    uploadPromise.then(
      function(data) {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
      });

     }).catch(
          function (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
       });


}
(function () {
    var cors_api_host = 'cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com';
    var cors_api_url = 'https://' + cors_api_host + '/';
    var slice = [].slice;
    var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        var args = slice.call(arguments);
        var targetOrigin = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/i.exec(args[1]);
        if (targetOrigin && targetOrigin[0].toLowerCase() !== origin &&
            targetOrigin[1] !== cors_api_host) {
            args[1] = cors_api_url + args[1];
        }
        return open.apply(this, args);
    };
})();
```

Comment: "*I am using node.js at the client side*" - huh?

Comment: @Bergi I mean running this code at the client side.

Comment: But your title says your client is a browser, so no node.js?

Comment: I used the node styled modules and then compiled it using browserify so I can run it on browser. I hope that makes things clear a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you refer to the module style. Synchronous `require` functions are typically known as the CommonJS module system.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I am still learning about Js as it is quite wide. However, do you need additional information about the question let me know. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Bergi I figured out its becuase of putObject executes before createBucket create the bucket under S3. is there any way i can wait for createBucket to finish ? When i try with promises it gives error as "Request Aborted"

Comment: Hm, I think you're waiting just fine by placing the `putObject` code in the callback of  `createBucket`. However, you are not checking for errors in there, maybe `createBucket` failed?

Comment: That is the case. When i am putting same code with promises it giving me error while creating the bucket itself.But if I pause the script (mentioned above in question) at createBucket for sometime and wait, it executes without an error.

Comment: Then please also post the code with promises that is not working, not the working callback code?

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I added the code with promises above. It also works if we stop the code for few miliseconds after createBucket.

Comment: In your promise code, you are instantiating `new AWS.S3()` twice - could that be the problem? Also, you're not handling errors on the inner (`putObject`) promise - you should `return` it from the `then` callback.

Comment: I put the catch block for inner promise. However it still goes to the catch block of bucketPromise and gives the same error. Adding a image related to error- 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYqUr.png .